# Regex Pattern - Ignore tab and grep word alone using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Input File:(all are tab separated)

```
abc   S12GG    HLPC
        WT4E    dfs.com   512
        SDA     djkf.com    1
        SWEW       abc.com    1
        SEFAW    dfsga.com    1
zyx   S12YT    TYSX
        wureyu    dfs.com   23
        ASWE     djkf.com    10
        werse       abc.com    16
        SDSDFS   dfsga.com    19
```

I am creating a hash table with the first line as one key and in the second line, just the first word as key. Below is the code:

```
sub readFile {
    my ($fileName, $hash) = @_;
    my $lines=0;
    my $key;
    my $buffer;

    open (INPUT, $fileName);
    while($buffer=<INPUT>) {
        $lines++;
        if ($buffer=~/^(.*)\t(.*)\t(.*)$/) {
            $key=trim($1).";".trim($2).";".trim($3).";";
            $buffer=<INPUT>;
            $lines++;
        }
        $buffer=~/\t(.+)\t(.+)\t(.+)/;
        my $item=trim($1);
        my $group=trim($2);
        my $colinfo=trim($3);
        $hash->{$key}{$item}=["$group","$colinfo"];
    }
    close (INPUT);

    return $lines;
}
```

But this one matches both the lines in the if condition:

```
if ($buffer=~/^(.*)\t(.*)\t(.*)$/)
```

This matches both

```
abc   S12GG    HLPC
        WT4E    dfs.com   512
```

Can the if condition match only the first line?? I am really stuck on this and breaking my head for a long time.

https://regex101.com/r/v6JuDb/1/

I tried to use it for help. But couldn't find any solution. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `(.*)`, use `([^\t]+)` so it won't match across a TAB delimiter, and it has to match at least one non-TAB character.

Comment: I changed from `*` to `+`, I think that should do it.

Answer (score 3):

The way I'd do it:

```
chomp($line);
if (!/^\t/) {
    $key = $line;
    next;
}

my (undef, $item, $group, $colinfo) = split(/\t/, $line);
$hash->{$key}{$item} = [ $group, $colinfo ];
```

Or if the key format actually matters,

```
chomp($line);
my @fields = split(/\t/, $line, -1);
if ($fields[0] ne "") {
    $key = join(';', @fields);
    next;
}

my (undef, $item, $group, $colinfo) = @fields;
$hash->{$key}{$item} = [ $group, $colinfo ];
```